# Can a widget in the Customizer be “single-use” (i.e. disabled after 1 instance has been added)?

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

I’m on a nightly quest to build a **custom single-use widget**.

As soon as one instance of it has been added to a sidebar panel **in the Customizer**, its control on the Available Widgets panel should be **displayed as disabled** (or alternatively, disappear entirely).

This is how it would look (note the visually “disabled” widget on the right):

[image: …]

The custom Widget is registered and all, but I’m stuck at the single-use requirement.

### Specs

- **Scale is not a problem.** It’s ok to assume only 1 registered sidebar. The approach can be to limit the use of the widget to either 1 per sidebar, or to 1 per *all* registered sidebars—both would be equally fine for now.
- **The Widgets page on the back-end is not a problem.** This is not required to work equally well on the *Widgets* page under *Appearance* on the back-end. It only has to work in the Customizer.

### Questions

1. About 250 years ago, all widgets used to be “single-use”. Does anyone know of a legit way to bring those times back and make a custom widget be used only 1x through the Widget API?
2. If not (which I’m assuming after having dug through a fair amount of core files), I’d probably defer to a CSS-based approach (pointer-events, pseudo element overlay, whatever). **Would any kind soul help my *very* limited Customizer/JavaScript knowledge with a basic approach on how to add/remove a dedicated CSS class to the widget control in the “available” panel (the one on the right) once an instance of said widget has been added/removed to the sidebar panel?**

### What I tried so far

- Dug through a fair chunk of core files.
- Read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/how-can-a-widget-with-only-one-instance-be-defined), and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32103/how-do-i-create-a-widget-that-only-allows-a-single-instance), but neither one seems practical.
- Tinkered with jQuery events `widget-added`, `widget-updated`, and `widget-synced`, but miss an event for “widget deleted”.

Thanks tons in advance!

---

<del>Update: Haven’t put my proof of concept on a public repo yet, would will do, of course.</del>

### Solution

I wrapped the solution kindly shared by kraftner below in a [proof of concept plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/glueckpress/single-use-widget).

Comment: You could also just use the classic widget API instead of `WP_Widget`, for example: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/7141599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Approach

So I've looked into this and my approach is this:

1. When launching the customizer go through all sidebars and disable the widget as soon as you find any usage of it
2. Whenever a sidebar is changed do that again.

#### Disclaimer

This has the following limitations:

1. This is the first time I've dabbled in playing with the JS API of the Customizer. So I might be doing inefficient stuff here, but hey, it works ;)
2. Only cares about the Customizer (as stated in the question)
3. Doesn't do any kind of server-side validation. It merely hides the UI, so if you're worried about someone circumventing the UI this is incomplete/insecure.
4. Disabling the widget is global - any use in any sidebar disables the widget globally.

---

#### The code

Now that we have the Disclaimer done let's look at the code:

```
(function() {
    wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() {

        var api = wp.customize,
            widgetId = 'foo_widget',
            widget = wp.customize.Widgets.availableWidgets.findWhere( { id_base: widgetId } );

        /**
         * Counts how often a widget is used based on an array of Widget IDs.
         *
         * @param widgetIds
         * @returns {number}
         */
        var countWidgetUses = function( widgetIds ){

            var widgetUsedCount = 0;

            widgetIds.forEach(function(id){

                if( id.indexOf( widgetId ) == 0 ){
                    widgetUsedCount++;
                }

            });

            return widgetUsedCount;

        };

        var isSidebar = function( setting ) {
            return (
                0 === setting.id.indexOf( 'sidebars_widgets[' )
                &&
                setting.id !== 'sidebars_widgets[wp_inactive_widgets]'
            );
        };

        var updateState = function(){

            //Enable by default...
            widget.set('is_disabled', false );

            api.each( function( setting ) {
                if ( isSidebar( setting ) ) {
                    //...and disable as soon as we encounter any usage of the widget.
                    if( countWidgetUses( setting.get() ) > 0 ) widget.set('is_disabled', true );
                }
            } );

        };

        /**
         * Listen to changes to any sidebar.
         */
        api.each( function( setting ) {
            if ( isSidebar( setting ) ) {
                setting.bind( updateState );
            }
        } );

        updateState();

    });
})( jQuery );
```

Sidenote: Use the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action to add the script.

---

You could probably extend this to limit it to work an a per sidebar base instead of globally. I'd say listen to the activation of a sidebar and then count the widgets in that sidebar. But I didn't find time to look into that as well.

Comment: Fantastic! I’m at a loss for words, this works like a charm and solves my case completely. Wouldn’t have expected a full working example, thanks so much!

Comment: Good questions (clear explanation, screenshots, prove of effort) deserve complete answers. Leaving this comment as a hint to other people how to get proper answers to their questions. ;)