# Allow a Widget to be used one time only?

Tags: customization, widgets

I am trying to only allow the use of all my widgets one time per widget. But searching a lot for this did not help me. I found something called `$settings['_multiwidget'] = 0;` but I don't know what it does, or how to set it.

It should work both in the Customizer and Widget screen.
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can A Widget With Only One Instance Be Defined?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/how-can-a-widget-with-only-one-instance-be-defined)